# SQL Return number of met conditions with each row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to order a result set by the number of met conditions that apply in each row.

If I have the following table

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
book_id | book_title
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|  54   | Learn SQL the easy way
|  56   | Mastering PHP
|  58   | PHP, MySQL Bible
|  59   | The complete guide to SQL
|  62   | learn MySQL in 24 hours
|  64   | How to build websites
|  69   | SQL stored procedures guide
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Now I want to run this query:

```
SELECT book_id 
from books 
where book_title ilike '%sql%' 
    OR book_title ilike '%guide%' 
    OR book_title ilike '%complete%'
```

I want to get the following results:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
book_id | met_conditions
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|  59   | 3
|  69   | 2
|  62   | 1
|  58   | 1
|  54   | 1
```

Where the met_conditions is the total number of applicable conditions that were met in each record.

Can I accomplish that in SQL? if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the conditions together in MySQL:

```
select book_id,
       ((book_title ilike '%sql%') +
        (book_title ilike '%guide%') +
        (book_title ilike '%complete%')
       ) as metConditions
from books
where book_title ilike '%sql%' OR book_title ilike '%guide%' OR book_title ilike '%complete%';
```

This works because MySQL treats boolean expressions as integers in a numeric context, with 0 for false and 1 for true.  The alternative is to use `case` expressions instead, something that works in any (reasonable) database.

This type of query might be better using a full-text index.  Then the relevance would be the metric that you want.  (Note:  by default, a full text index would ignore SQL because it has three letters; setting the minimum word length parameter fixes this.)

Comment: Works exactly as wanted but the performance is very slow. Searching 1 million records would return 50 records in 11 seconds. Do you have any tips to increase the speed of such query? Thanks a lot @gordon-linoff ! I am accepting your answer.

Comment: @RaedN. . . . Hence you want a full text index, as suggested in the answer.

Comment: unfortunately we are using an InnoDB table on MySQL 5.4 so we cannot use full text index and we cannot upgrade the server due to environment restrictions so we are trying to accomplish this using the best possible method at our hands.